# ggplotly error on guide_colorbar "object 'tickvals' not found"

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggplotly

I am trying to use `ggplotly` to make an interactive plot with some `geom_ribbon`s.

The plot looks like (data made using the `tidyverse` packages):

```
temp_data <-
   tibble(Group = 1, x = 1) %>%
   complete(Group = 1:3, x = 1:10) %>%
   mutate(y_val = x + Group * 5
          , ymin = y_val - 3/Group
          , ymax = y_val + 3/Group)

temp_plot <-
    ggplot(temp_data
           , aes(x = x
                 , ymin = ymin
                 , ymax = ymax
                 , fill = Group
                 , group = Group)) +
    geom_ribbon()
```

The plot is then:

[image]

Which is the plot I want. However, when I go to render it in `plotly` with `ggplot(temp_plot)`, I get the error:

> Error in eval(substitute(expr), data, enclos = parent.frame()) :
>   object 'tickvals' not found

I can track this down to the `geom_ribbon` element, and specifically the legend. If I run `ggplotly(temp_plot + theme(legend.position = "none"))`, the plot renders fine (without the legend).

I am running the latest stable releases of both `ggplot2` (ggplot2_3.2.0.9000) and `plotly` (plotly_4.9.0). Of note, I do **not** get this error on a server that is running an older version of ggplot2 (ggplot2_3.1.1), but is current on `plotly`.

Comment: Why not plot everything with `ggplot2` and call `ggplotly` on the last plot? Is there  any reason to save the plot? Do you need to show the legend?

Comment: If you eliminate saving your plot and simply call: `plotly::ggplotly()`,you get an interactive plot as in the question. Perhaps I misunderstood your aim.

Comment: Thanks @NelsonGon. These are being created inside a `shiny` application where I have functions that return plots that can either be rendered as interactive or not (with `plotly` or without) depending on app settings and in a report generated from the app (that is interactive if html and non-interactive if pdf), so it is important to be able to store the plot. In any case, I still get the error if I wrap `ggplotly` around the code or call it on the last generated plot. For the actual use case, the legend is important.

Comment: I unfortunately can't reproduce your issue. I used this and it works as expected: `plotly::ggplotly(p=my_plot)`. I'm using plotly 4.9.0 and ggplot2 3.2.1

Comment: Interesting ... I just upgraded to ggplot2 3.2.1.9000 (the dev version from github), but I am still getting the error. I will try to dig deeper.

Comment: I can reproduce the problem with ggplot2 3.3.0 and plotly 4.8.0